# addPeer() to Ethereum system with different IP address (connect with Google cloud)

Tags: private-blockchain

I try to make now a private Ethereum system but can not add peers to it. I tried with static-node.json and with Javascript console (admin.addPeer).

The problem is that I installed miners on google cloud and try now to use it public IP. And my nodes works locally.

How I try:
`admin.addPeer("enode://237860fd43f04d9409aa75acf465afba17952add2242f3f1399e2114521d82ed8ef1f52d5396dff72cd6db8442bb87584c4f0fc7f645bc6a71c3a1a8fb55beec@192.168.0.222:30305");`

`addPeer("enode://2gf52074d040624359e45a7476ba7b7bd2668606768d0f2c3c8872fdc9b6fc3554700c0e3321788218796835867ae059a12edaf3fd22aefd862ebf4848a79bff@35.240.196.190:30303")`

192.168.0.222 -> my home IP 
35.240.196.190 -> IP of computer engine on google cloud.

I reinstalled the genesis file for both nodes. And tried also with static-node.json. If I addPeers  only on Google Cloud or only locally, it works.

Could you suggest where can be a problem?

Comment: Can you please make the question a little bit clearer? I mean what are the IPs of your local computer and which are those of google cloud (the arrows are confusing :) ). 
BTW 192.168.0.22 seems a private ip, obviously your local computer cannot access to google cloud internal ips..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem was with the firewall rule of google cloud. The problem was solved:)